# Not able to load html resource in mono android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

When I access the html file in Assets folder in visual studio 2010 (mono android) I get error

```
invalid resource directory name : assets
```

in mono android

I have tried these code combination but to no avail

```
        //webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/mapapp/index.html");
        //webView.LoadUrl("file:///AndroidAsset/mapapp/index.html");
        //webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/mapapp/index.html");
        //webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/mapapp", "index.html", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        webView.LoadUrl("file:///AndroidAsset/TextFile1.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with this,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class StackOverFlowActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
    }

    final class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
            {             
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                            {
                                //do anything here...
                            }
                    });
            }
    }
}
```

If your html file is inside of assets folder try the above.

[image]

If it is placed inside any of the folder give like

```
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image/index.html");
```

[image]

Comment: It should be exactly the same. Try creating a new test project with only a webview and the one asset. No need for the javascript interface though.

Answer (score 1):

I had few icons and images that were being considered as AndroidResource by mono android, changing them to AndroidAsset removed the error.